# Building combined armv7/x86 apk after Crosswalk integration in an Ionic project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk-runtime

I have added Crosswalk to my ionic project. When i do `ionic build android` it outputs two separate APK files, one for armv7 and one for x86.

However i want one single apk file bundling two architectures together.

I tried setting `BUILD_MULTIPLE_APKS = false` but it's still building two separate apks.

There is a post [here](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/crosswalk-integration-beta-in-ionic-cli-v1-3-2/15190/258) saying :

> Took me a minute but you can get the single build file by commenting
>   out the  cdvBuildMultipleApks=true line in the
>   platforms/android/gradle.properties
>
> Cheers

But i don't have any gradle.properties file in my platforms/android/ folder, i have a project.properties file and there is no `cdvBuildMultipleApks=true` line in it to comment out.

I tried to manually create a gradle.properties file and putting `cdvBuildMultipleApks=false` in there but still two outputs.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

**Update:**

My Cordova version is 5.1.1

**Solution:**

What did work for me as suggested by @mudasserajaz and [here](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/crosswalk-integration-beta-in-ionic-cli-v1-3-2/15190/294), was to :

1. Create a file named `build-extras.gradle` inside my `/platform/android/` directory.
2. put `ext.cdvBuildMultipleApks=false` inside it.
3. `ionic build android --release` then and Voila, it worked.

@mudasserajaz suggested the same thing except variable name is `cdvBuildMultipleApks=false` so in case it didn't work out for you, don't forget the `ext`

Comment: what is your cordova version?

Comment: @mudasserajaz, my Cordova version is  5.1.1

Comment: Just add <preference name="xwalkMultipleApk" value="false"/> to the config.xml file.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here are steps to do that:

1. Make a file `build-extras.gradle` and put it into `platforms/android/`. Add line `cdvBuildMultipleApks=false` into `build-extras.gradle`.
2. Now run `ionic run android`, it will create combined single build `android-debug.apk`.

`build.gradle` will automaticaly import `build-extras.gradle`,if that is defined.You can see code of `build.gradle` doing this :

```
def hasBuildExtras = file('build-extras.gradle').exists()
if (hasBuildExtras) {
    apply from: 'build-extras.gradle'
}
```

Plus these instructions are clearly mentioned in `build.gradle` line 57 :

> Configuration properties. Set these via environment variables,
>   build-extras.gradle, or gradle.properties.

**NOTE:** Before you follow these steps, remove platform folder and install again.

**Observations:** Once you have done these steps, and again at some point, you want to make separate builds, then setting `cdvBuildMultipleApks=true`  or commenting out sometimes won't work, you will simply have to install platform again. (P.S this is my personal observation, otherwise deleting `build-extras.gradle` should be enough.)

Comment: Creating `build-extras.gradle` in `platforms/android/` and adding the line `cdvBuildMultipleApks=false` inside it worked like a charm!

Comment: Oh i realized my variable name inside `build-extras.gradle` was `ext.cdvBuildMultipleApks=false`. So in case the other one didn't work, don't forget the ext.

Comment: Regarding  your update, to make separate builds, I deleted my `build-extras.gradle` file and again it made two separate files. So maybe just doing that or commenting the `cdvBuildMultipleApks=false` is enough.

Comment: those are just my observations, which i faced on my system. Otherwise you are right, deleting file should be enough.

Comment: This is still the way to do it? It is not working for me trying with both cdvBuildMultipleApks=false and ext.cdvBuildMultipleApks=false

Comment: No need for this much hassle. The next answer does an even better job without making any new files.  Also be sure to check @Henry 
Luo's answer as well. I ended up using the armv7 apk. When I combined both armv7 and x86, the size of the apk grew almost 3 times. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535551/building-combined-armv7-x86-apk-after-crosswalk-integration-in-an-ionic-project#answer-39109304 (link for the next answer in case it changes its positon)

Answer (score 46):

Well I just changed my **`config.xml`** following property to `false` and it combined the build apk.

from

```
<preference name="xwalkMultipleApk" value="true"/>
```

to

```
<preference name="xwalkMultipleApk" value="false"/>
```

My systems `ionic info` returns

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.1.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.16
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.3
OS:
Node Version: v4.4.4
```

Comment: This worked for me. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with a project created with Tools for Apache Cordova. I'm using Cordova CLI 5.4.1. I just added the preference to the `<platform name="android">` section of my `config.xml`

Comment: This also worked for me, except the <preference/> for xwalk was not part of my original config.xml.

Answer (score 3):

As of today, in 2018, we probably can ignore x86 mobile platform, as there's indeed hardly any mobile using Intel CPU.

This has the advantage of a smaller APK. A single-platform APK is smaller than the multi-platform APK.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check the output folder.

I noticed that "cordova build" was still output both arm7 and x86 after adding to my build-extra.gradle but the output folder contained "android-release.apk" as well.

Deleting both arm7 and x86 APK's from the output folder (project/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/)

it immediately stopped them from being shown by "corodva build".

Hope this helps.