# Cordova Crosswalk Plugin failing with "Unfortunately, {appName} has stopped."

Tags: android, cordova, webview, crosswalk

After updating to [cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview) version `1.3.0` I get the following error dialog when opening my app:

**Unfortunately, {appName} has stopped.**

And the app then quits. I've [tried removing all the other plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662320/ionic-crosswalk-crashing-on-samsung-s6-device) in my app, and the error persists. If I downgrade to version `1.2.0`, the app launches as expected.

I would have created this as an issue on [their github project](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview), but seems like they don't allow that.

My test phone is currently a Samsung S5 (SM G900F). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: source your plugin from NPM. Read #11 [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

Comment: @JesseMonroy650, I'm installing it (and all my other plugins) with `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`, and using Cordova **v5.3.3**, so pretty sure that's already covered?

Comment: I do not use Cordova CLI. I cannot say for sure. You might ask your question at [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap)

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution.  I'm having the same issue now.

Comment: @Kauthon, I actually don't remember by now. I think I ended up solving it by reinstalling all my plugins over again. Cordova is such a fragile piece of software, so a tiny misconfiguration might trip up you whole application - and that misconfiguration often comes from installing and uninstalling plugins. To be honest, we finished this project, and I don't see myself working with Cordova ever again unless it's a VERY simple project.

Answer (score 0):

You can file an issue on https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/, I am not sure which Crosswalk you tried, but better check the compatibility between plugin and Crosswalk lib. version `1.3` requires Crosswalk 14+.