# include crosswalk in combined armv7 x86 apk

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk

I've attempted the solution outlined in [building-combined-armv7-x86-apk-after-crosswalk-integration-in-an-ionic-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535551/building-combined-armv7-x86-apk-after-crosswalk-integration-in-an-ionic-project).

The great thing is that it creates a single apk file.  But when I run my cordova application, I get the following alert:

```
Mismatch of CPU Architecture
The Crosswalk Project Service must be updated to match the CPU architecture of the device. Please install it from the app store, then restart app.
```

Looks like Crosswalk is not embedded in the combined apk.

Does anyone know how to embed Crosswalk in a combined apk?

Answer (score 2):

After I had spent a lot time looking for I solved it:

If you open the ".apk" file generated with a compressor (like WinRar), inside folder "lib" you are going to see folders for different architectures (x86_64, x86, mips64, mips, armeabi-v7a, armeabi and arm64-v8a in my case). After inspect all them only x86 and armeabi-v7a have "libxwalkdummy.so" and "libxwalkcore.so" files, so I deleted which ones do not have it. So "lib" folder will only contain x86 and armeabi-v7a folders.

After that it seems that app works with crosswalk embedded.