# How can i come to know which apk will work on my devise in ionic?

Tags: ubuntu, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic.
I just added crosswalk and trying to build apt

```
$ ionic build android
```

Before this i was just getting 2 apps in project-folder/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/ but after adding i am getting 6 akps.

I am just wondering which will work on my devise?

else shall i remove crosswalk to get appropriate apk by-

Removing Crosswalk

```
$ ionic browser revert android
# or
$ ionic browser remove crosswalk
```

I also saw [Building combined armv7/x86 apk after Crosswalk integration in an Ionic project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535551/building-combined-armv7-x86-apk-after-crosswalk-integration-in-an-ionic-project)

Hope for help...

Answer (score 0):

to know which apk will work just look in the

[image: pic]

You can see that at last line you it is showing the path of the particular `android-debug.apk` file will be loaded into device

Comment: Thanks for your reply @mohan
But i have 6 apks like
1. android-armv7-debug-unaligned.apk
2. android-armv7-debug.apk
3. android-armv7-release-unsigned.apk
4. android-x86-debug-unaligned.apk
5. android-x86-debug.apk
6. android-x86-release-unsigned.apk

Comment: @S.Yadav s if you have installed crosswalk you will get like that

Comment: @S.Yadav so what is your need what do you want. you asked you need to know which apk is installing to device so i have shown you the example where the installed apk will be present and what apk is installed

Comment: So shall i remove crasswalk to get this done?
if yes then how?

Comment: if you read description you can understand what I wrote and what i need.
thanks @mohan

Comment: go to your plugin folder and remove cross walk plugin or in cmd do this `ionic plugin rm cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview` .

Comment: what is the command you try to install crosswalk can you tell me

Comment: I used ionic browser install crosswalk but it won't get install as it gave error as-   _             _          
 (_)           (_)         
  _  ___  _ __  _  ___     
 | |/ _ \| '_ \| |/ __| 
 | | (_) | | | | | (__     
 |_|\___/|_| |_|_|\___|  CLI v2.0.0-beta.31

Usage: ionic task args


=======================
browser is not a valid task.

Comment: do you find any corss walk folder inside your plugin folder of your project

Comment: Thanks @Mohan Gopi,
i Removed crosswork and now required apk i have.