# ionic 2 + genymotion: Crosswalk Mismatch of CPU Architecture

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2, genymotion, crosswalk

I am try to deploy and run an simple ionic 2 app on my genymotion emulator with
this command:

```
$ ionic run android
```

But I get this error message:

[image]

I had a look at this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535551/building-combined-armv7-x86-apk-after-crosswalk-integration-in-an-ionic-project) but it did not work for me.

Thanks for your help