# Ionic2: This app isn't compatible with your phone

Tags: android, performance, cordova, ionic2, crosswalk

After installing my Ionic2 app on real device, it became slow - which wasn't while testing on browser during development. Then I came across Crollwalk, a tool/plugin to enhance Hybrid app performance on device.

I then generated an .apk and attempted to install on real-device, only to get the error "***This app isn't compatible with your phone***".

After few Bing/Google searches, I got to know that the project was last supported for WebView on Cordova 6.3 at the [Crosswalk Project](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/11/09/android-release.html) official website.

My dev env is 
Cordova: 6.5.0,
Ionic: 2.2.3

**How do I downgrade Cordova to the supported version of Crosswalk without affecting Ionic and the project it self?**

Thanks for your usual assistance.

Comment: what is the android version you need to support?

Comment: @SurajRao minimum version of Android 5.0 because I am aware that Crosswalk doesn't work with Android 4.0. Meanwhile, I already added  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="20"/> to my config.xml. I increased it to 21 but still having same issue. Thanks.

Comment: If min version support needed is 5 you can just remove the crosswalk plugin and check.. crosswalk was for supporting version 4.. you dont need to downgrade cordova

Comment: But my app is slow on real device. I need to gain performance and that was how I stubbled on Crosswalk to gain native performance. It is really slow.

Comment: Finaly, I got a walkaround!
I had to `build-extras.gradle` file and add `cdvBuildMultipleApks=false`.
That now generated a single unsigned apk which I signed & was able to launch the app!

Thanks for your support.

Comment: You could add your workaround as an answer and accept it to help future users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got a walk-around!

I had to create `build-extras.gradle` file and added `cdvBuildMultipleApks=false` to it. That now generated a single unsigned apk file (instead of `armv7` and `x86` respectively) which I signed & was able to launch the app!

Before then, I used to sign the `android-x86-release-unsigned.apk`.

Thanks to [building-combined-armv7-x86-apk-after-crosswalk-integration-in-an-ionic-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535551/building-combined-armv7-x86-apk-after-crosswalk-integration-in-an-ionic-project)