# Cordova CLI: Mismatch of CPU architecture

Tags: android, cordova, cpu-architecture, crosswalk, cordova-cli

I've been searching through CLI docs, SO questions, Cordova issues and more for quite some time, but I'm stumped.

So I've created a simple Cordova app for Android using Crosswalk (`cordova create`, `cordova platform add android`, `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`, `cordova build android`, nothing fancy). This, by default, generates a bunch of apk's on `cordova build` which is fine.

But then `cordova run android --device` installs the `arm64` apk which crashes at startup on my device with the message `Mismatch of CPU Architecture` - with a button to the store to `GET CROSSWALK` - which is not what I want.

I'd like to instruct `cordova run android --device` to install and run the `armv7` apk, which runs perfectly fine if installed manually via `adb install`. How can I do this?

- cordova v8.0.0
- cordova-android v7.0.0
- cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview v2.4.0

Notes:

- this is for a `debug` build for local development, not for `release`.
- using `cordova-android@6.4.0` instead of `7.0.0` works fine, it installs the correct apk.

Thank you!

Comment: follow this steps & generate the apk https://stackoverflow.com/a/26450074/4973660

Comment: I'm sorry @kirankumar, i wasn't clear enough. It's not a release build, but a debug build for local development. Also, those steps indicate an `ant` build, whereas the default builder (and which i'd like to use because it's the latest and recommended one) is `gradle`. Also i failed to specify that a similar build using `cordova-android@6.4.0` works as intended. So i don't see how those steps would apply here, maybe i am missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've resolved this issue follow @Mtz recommendation:

1) Install https://github.com/MBuchalik/cordova-build-architecture plugin adding to config.xml like this

```
<plugin name="cordova-build-architecture" spec="https://github.com/MBuchalik/cordova-build-architecture.git#v1.0.4" source="git" />
```

2) Add this preference to android section in config.xml:

```
<preference default="arm" name="buildArchitecture" />
```

3)

```
cordova clean
cordova build (This step only generates one apk, armv7)
cordova run --devices
```

The run command will install only armv7 version, remember to remove all apk from your device before trying this

Comment: It's been a while, and since then i stuck with `adb` from a script for convenience (it can uninstall any existing `.apk` from the device). However, this is the closest answer for my question. Well done, sir.

Answer (score 3):

Crosswalk git repository report same issue: https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/issues/203

Some user has resolved by open android studio and change default architecture, but i dont know what cordova suitable settings or configurations android studio change with that.

> I solved the problem. I found that the plugin works correctly in my
> case. The problem was with the **Android Studio**. Android Studio 3.0.1
> uses **arm64Debug** by default. To solve this problem I have taken the
> following steps in the Android Studio:
>
> - click on the app Build
> - Select Build Variant
> - Select armv7Debug

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi there! Unfortunately i am not using Android Studio, and - you didn't have any way of knowing this but - the last comment on that bug is mine, i'm Teodor Sandu, nice to meet you :) Back on topic, it's not solving the actual issue. Android Studio is not using `cordova run` internally, which is what i wanted to use (because it's a cli command, not a program i need to open manually, because it does uninstall, install and launch in one go, and because it's basically what *should* work out of the box with cordova cli). Thank you for your time though, i appreciate it!

Comment: You got a +1 vote from me for providing context and a working alternative, even though it's not what i was looking for - maybe for others it will suffice. Thanks again :)

Comment: Have you tryed with this ? [https://github.com/MBuchalik/cordova-build-architecture](https://github.com/MBuchalik/cordova-build-architecture)  Is a plugin to allow you to set desired architecture via config.xml. It patch default cordova gradle file.

Comment: I've seen that as well, thanks, but that plugin is involved in the build process, not in the installation :|

Answer (score 1):

By default, Cordova generate a build.gradle file which changes according to your program behavior or plugins you installed.

In case you only need to install/run your apk for armv7 for debug purpose set the **cdvBuildMultipleApks** property to false.

check out this [Setting Gradle Properties](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/#setting-gradle-properties) for **cdvBuildMultipleApks** property and allso, [Build Environment UserGuide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html) for setting it in the currect place.

this may allso be helpfull aswell: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535551/building-combined-armv7-x86-apk-after-crosswalk-integration-in-an-ionic-project)

Comment: Thank you for trying, but that's not what i'm talking about. 1: it's not about the build, it's about `cordova run` not installing the correct apk for my device's architecture - it just chooses the wrong one, although the good one is built and works perfectly if i install it manually via `adb install`. 2: i do NOT want to set `cdvBuildMultipleApks` to `false` because the resulting apk is too large (and it doesn't quite make sense to me to ship 20Mb+ of code that will never be used). That said, thank you for your time! I appreciate it :)

Comment: you're welcome. i guess there is no magics regarding to deployment. i guess if you could just do it through CLI it will be perfect (like: cordova run android --device --arm7) but you can't . you'll  need to interfered with the build itself. hope some one will give you another point of view on this issue :)