# Ionic uses the CrossWalk plug-in to generate the specified version of APK

Tags: cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugins, cpu, crosswalk

I'm using cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 2.4.0, which generates 5 versions of APK at a time, including arm64, armeabi, armv7, x86 and x86_64. I just want to generate a armv7, the others do not want to generate, what should be done？

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.
- remove platform android
- add a file build-extras.gradle which contains the line
cdvBuildMultipleApks=false

Try build again

More details here

[Building combined armv7/x86 apk after Crosswalk integration in an Ionic project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535551/building-combined-armv7-x86-apk-after-crosswalk-integration-in-an-ionic-project)